# Parsing an address: T-SQL code to mimic these 8 lines of Perl?

Tags: sql, perl, t-sql, parsing

I'm just getting an unparsed address from another program and I need to store it as its components in the receiving system.  And I need some help!  I'll wash your cat.  Anything.

Good news is I can count on those line feeds.  I can count on that comma+space after city and I can count on the two digit abbreviation for state or province followed by space.  So (without golfing) I wrote it up in Perl quickly to provide some working code.

The key is if we split the input on the \n I just want the second line/element (Address 1), the last line/element (Country), and the second to last element (City, ST zip).  I then need to split that element into its components.  My Perl code below works, but how do I recreate it in T-SQL?

```
$_ = "Company\n".
    "Address 1\n".
    "Address 2 (opt)\n".
    "Address 3 (opt)\n".
    "City, ST zip\n".   
    "Country";

# also works for "City, PV zip zip\n"

@add = split('\n');

$address = $add[1]; # who cares about addy and addy3
$country = pop(@add);
$ctz = pop(@add);
if ($ctz =~ /(.*), (..) (.*)/) {
    # Yes a $ctz line like "City of Angels, II, MO 65423" would break it
    $city = $1;
    $state = $2;
    $zip = $3;
} else {
    $city = $state = $zip = '';
}

print "Address: $address\n".
    "City: $city\n".
    "State Code: $state\n".
    "Zip: $zip\n".
    "Country: $country\n";
```

Comment: Actually, that regex would parse `City of Angels, II, MO 65423` just fine

Comment: Oh right Greedy.  Well I'm sure there's some weird city name that would fail us.  But man just saying take the last line, the second to last line split it up, and take the second line in tsql is driving me nuts.  The integrator has like 50 lines of code and it fails.  I paid someone on Fiver but his code didn't work either and it wasn't worth fighting him over the $20.  Someone?

Comment: Did you try the regex? -- I find lots of examples [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/t-sql-regex-commands-in-sql-server/).  I'm sure there's far more docs out there.  if yes, what in particular gives you trouble (I didn't get the description from the previous comment, about the "last line" then "second of last" then "second" ... can you show the exact line?  (Or, better yet, your `SQL` attempt?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a little ugly but I taught myself TSQL today.  :)

```
declare @string varchar(2000), @ctz varchar(100), @delim varchar(1), @idx integer;

set @delim = CHAR(10);  -- What we get from BC
set @string = 'Company'+@delim+'Address1'+@delim+'Address2'+@delim+'City, ST Zip'+@delim+'Country'; -- We we get from BC
--set @string = 'Company'+@delim+'Address1'+@delim+'City, ST Zip'+@delim+'Country'; -- We we get from BC
--set @string = 'Company'+@delim+'Address1'+@delim+'Address2'+@delim++'Address3'+@delim+'City, PR zip zip'+@delim+'Country'; -- We we get from BC

-- Start from the bottom
select @idx = LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX(@delim,REVERSE(@string)) + 1;    -- last occurance of our delim
select SUBSTRING(@string,@idx+1,2000) as country;

select @string = SUBSTRING(@string,1,@idx-1);   -- shorten our string now including the delim

select @idx = LEN(@string) - CHARINDEX(@delim,REVERSE(@string)) + 1;
select @ctz = SUBSTRING(@string,@idx+1,2000); -- deal with this later
-- select @ctz as ctz;

select @string = SUBSTRING(@string,1,@idx-1);  -- shorten it again including the delim

-- Now start at the top to remove company

select @idx = CHARINDEX(@delim, @string); -- first occurance of delim
select @string = SUBSTRING(@string,@idx+1,2000); -- just remove everything up to that point (Company)

select @idx = CHARINDEX(@delim, @string); -- first occurance at end of add1

if @idx = 0
    select @string as address1;
else 
    BEGIN
    select SUBSTRING(@string,1,@idx-1) as address1;
    select @string = SUBSTRING(@string,@idx+1,2000); -- keep shortening
    select replace(@string, @delim, ',') as address2; -- if there anything else
    END

select @idx = PATINDEX('%, [A-z][A-Z] %',@ctz); -- A regexp to find ", ST "
select SUBSTRING(@ctz,1,@idx-1) as city;
select SUBSTRING(@ctz,@idx+2,2) as st;
select SUBSTRING(@ctz,@idx+1+2+1,100) as zip; -- index+space+state+space
GO
```

Answer (score 1):

Start with a string splitter that borrows heavily from [Jeff Moden](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/tally-oh-an-improved-sql-8k-%E2%80%9Ccsv-splitter%E2%80%9D-function), but that handles a multiple character separator. It returns the separated items in order and with an index column:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter VARCHAR(16))
--WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 1 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "base" CTE and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT TOP (ISNULL(DATALENGTH(@pString),0)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL
                 SELECT t.N+ Len( @pDelimiter ) FROM cteTally t WHERE SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N, Len( @pDelimiter ) ) = @pDelimiter
                ),
cteLen(N1,L1) AS(--==== Return start and length (for use in substring)
                 SELECT s.N1,
                        ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1 ,8000)
                   FROM cteStart s
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY l.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString, l.N1, l.L1)
   FROM cteLen l;
```

Then turn it loose on your data:

```
declare @Newline as Char(2) = Char(13) + Char(10); -- This may need work to match your newlines.
declare @Sample as VarChar(1024) =
  'Company' + @Newline +
  'Address 1' + @Newline +
  'Address 2 (opt)' + @Newline +
  'Address 3 (opt)' + @Newline +
  'City, ST zip' + @Newline +
  'Country';

select *
  from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K( @Sample, @Newline );
```

Left as an exercise is figuring out how you want to handle optional items.

[DBfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=a3af702193da92a02b7ea5518d507e5e) for the curious.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, my bad I thought that you need the code in perl -- but you asked for T-SQL code.

Will leave the code for some stranger who can be interested in it.

Investigate the following code piece for compliance with your task

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my @data = <DATA>;
my $address;

chomp @data;

$address->{company} = $data[0];
push @{$address->{street}}, @data[1..$#data-2];
$address->@{qw/city state zip/} = split '[, ]+', $data[-2];
$address->{country} = $data[-1];

say Dumper($address);

say '--- Print the address ' . '-' x 25;

my @fields = keys %{ $address };

for my $field ( @fields ) {
    say ucfirst $field . ": " . 
            (
                ref $address->{$field} eq 'ARRAY' 
                ? join "\n\t", @{ $address->{$field} } 
                : $address->{$field}
            );
}

__DATA__
Company
Address 1
Address 2 (opt)
Address 3 (opt)
City, ST zip   
Country
```

Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'city' => 'City',
          'country' => 'Country',
          'company' => 'Company',
          'state' => 'ST',
          'zip' => 'zip',
          'street' => [
                        'Address 1',
                        'Address 2 (opt)',
                        'Address 3 (opt)'
                      ]
        };

--- Print the address -------------------------
Street: Address 1
        Address 2 (opt)
        Address 3 (opt)
City: City
State: ST
Zip: zip
Country: Country
```